# Not getting the desired output by converting php array into json

Tags: php, json

I receive names and links of some files from an external website and convert it into a JSON string using the following code:

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');
$f = $_GET['f'];
$w = "www.something.com";
$dom = file_get_html($w);
$arr = array("file" => array());

foreach($dom->find('div[id=file_html] div[id=right_data]') as $top){

$n = $top->find('div', 0)->childNodes(0)->innertext;
$l = $top->find('div', 2)->childNodes(0)->childNodes(0)->childNodes(0)->href;
$jj[] = array('name' => $n, 'link' => $l);


}
array_push($arr['file'], $jj);

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

The output I expect is

```
{"songs":[{"name":"file1","link":"link1"},{"name":"file2","link":"link2"}]}
```

But the output i get is:

```
{"songs":[[{"name":"file1","link":"link1"},{"name":"file2","link":"link2"}]]}
```

Could someone kindly point out the error in my code? 
Thank you

Comment: Try `$arr['file'] = $jj;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this one,

```
$arr = array("file" => array());
```

after iteration of `foreach()`

```
foreach($dom->find('div[id=file_html] div[id=right_data]') as $top){
  // as it is....
}

$arr['file'] = $jj;
```

Comment: I need the "file" JSONArray.. Is there any other way I can have it there?